# Is it possible to let the compiler infer the types of a templated struct/class?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
template<typename T,typename R>
struct match_struct{
  T t;
  std::function<R(T)> f;
};

template<typename T,typename R>
match_struct<T,R> match(T t,std::function<R(T)>f) {
  return match_struct<T,R>{t,f};
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto m = match<int,int>(10, [](int i){ return i;});
  return 0;
}
```

I know that I have to specify the types explicitly when I want to create a struct/class. I thought that I could just create a templated function that would infer the types automatically.

So that I can just write

```
auto m = match(10, [](int i){ return i;});
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Is there a workaround for this? So that I don't have to specify the types explicitly?

Comment: Basically, instead of having `match_struct` accept a `std::function`, you have it accept any arbitrary type like `template<typename T, typename F, typename R = typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type> match_struct<T, R> match(T t, F f)`.

Comment: Here's a live example of what I'm talking about: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30d09de001a7275a